# Deciding whether a Turing machine decides a language $L$ in at most $n^2$ steps

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, rice-theorem

Let $L$ be a language for which there exists some turing machine deciding it in at most $n^2$ steps.

> Is it decidable whether a given turing machine $M$ decides $L$ and runs in at most $n^2$ steps?

I expect the answer to always be "No", regardless of $L$, but I fail to see exactly how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is indeed undecidable, assuming that $n$ is not a constant but refers to the length of the machine's input.

Consider the problem $P$ of, given a Turing machine $\mathcal{M}$, to decide if it runs in at most $|x|$ steps on every input $x$.
Problem $P$ is undecidable.

For any constants $c,c' > 0$, let $Q_{L,c,c'}$ be the (promise) problem of:

- given a Turing machine $\mathcal{M}$ such that, for every $x$, either $\mathcal{M}$ halts on $x$ in at most $c\cdot |x|^2 + c'$ steps, or does not halt,
- decide if it runs in at most $c\cdot |x|^2 + c'$ steps on every input $x$ and decides $L$.

**Claim:** There exists $c,c'>0$ such that problem $P$ reduces to problem $Q_{L,c,c'}$.

*Proof:* Let $\mathcal{N_L}$ be the Turing machine which decides $L$ in at most $n^2$ steps. The reduction maps $\mathcal{M}$ to the machine $\mathcal{M}'$ which, on input $x$:

- first, it simulates $\mathcal{M}$ on input $x$ for $|x|$ steps;
- if the machine didn't stop, it loops forever;
- otherwise, it simulates $\mathcal{N}_L$ on $x$ for $|x|^2$ steps, and returns its output.

Then $\mathcal{M}$ runs in at most $|x|$ steps for every input $x$ if and only if $\mathcal{M}'$ decides $L$ and runs in at most $c\cdot |x|^2 + c'$ steps for every input $x$ for some constants $c,c'$.

Then, using the [linear speadup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_speedup_theorem), you can show that the following problem is undecidable: given $\mathcal{M}$, does $\mathcal{M}$ decide $L$ and halts in at most
\begin{cases}
|x|^2 \text{ steps} & \text{on every input $x$ of size at least $n_0$}, \\
k \text{ steps} & \text{on every input $x$ of size at most $k$}, \\
\end{cases}
for some constant $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$.
This problem differs from yours only on finitely many inputs, and so your problem is undecidable.